# Data sync between temporal tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, data-synchronization, temporal-tables

I want to Sync data between two databases which have system-versioned(temporal) tables. The data sync option in Azure does not support temporal tables and I need to find another way of doing the sync between the databases.

I want to copy the data from one temporal table to another temporal table of another database using Azure data factory.Will Azure data factory support the data sync between temporal tables?

What will be the best way of syncing data between the two databases that have identical temporal tables?

Comment: Are your two databases  both local SQL Sverver instance?

Comment: @LeonYue No they are not local instances and the two databases are on two different servers.

Comment: Two database on two different Azure SQL server?

Comment: @LeonYue yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a system-versioned(temporal) table in my Azure SQL database followed this document [Creating a temporal table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-2017#creating-a-temporal-table-with-a-default-history-table):

```
CREATE TABLE Department   
(    
     DeptID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
   , DeptName varchar(50) NOT NULL  
   , ManagerID INT  NULL  
   , ParentDeptID int NULL  
   , SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL  
   , SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL  
   , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)     
)   
WITH    
   (   
      SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.DepartmentHistory)   
   )   
;
```

I created two temporal tables Department and Department2 in different Azure SQL Server.

I test in the Data Factory copy active, choose the Department as source dataset, we can see the temporal table from the settings:
[image]

Choose the Department2 as link dataset, Table mapping::
[image]

Column mapping:
[image]

Active run succeeded:
[image]

That's mean Azure Data Factory support copy the data from one temporal table to another temporal table of another database.

**Update:**

Please reference this document: [Temporal Tables in SQL Server 2016 – Part III](https://sqland.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/temporal-tables-in-sql-server-2016-part-iii/).

Now, starting by INSERT, remember there are two datetime2 special columns in a temporal table declared as GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START / END.
These are the PERIOD columns and they are mandatory but you cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column. Its values will be automatically filled.
When you insert a new row in the table, the “ROW START” column will have the value of SYSUTCDATETIME() (yes, don’t forget it’s UTC time!) and the “ROW END” column will have the value: ‘9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999’
Basically when inserting a new row in a temporal table, regarding these two columns, you can use of the following options:
1. Use a column list and omit these two columns;
2. Use a column list without omitting these two columns and specify DEFAULT in the values list for each.
3. Don’t use a column list and specify DEFAULT in the values list for each.

Congratulations, the error has solved by yourself:

> 1. Loading the tables after switching off the versioning on the destination table and it worked.

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] SET(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF); ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME;`

> 2. Then after the copy active done, switch it back.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime); ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] SET(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this and tried to sync one row. But getting the following error because we can't add an explicit value into SysStartTime and SysEndTime.
"Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table"

Comment: Thanks @Leon Yeu. But in that case we will loose the sysStartTime and SysEndTime in the first table and it will insert new values. I want to retain the sysStartTime and SysEndTime  from first table and load the same during the data sync.

Comment: @Sindu_How about copy data from one temporal table to another normal table with the same schema?

Comment: I tried loading the tables after switching off the versioning on the destination table and it worked. 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] SET(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME;

Comment: Then we can switch it back on: 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime); 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] SET(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);

Comment: @Sindu_Congratulations!  Can I put this to my answer? That's may be very useful to others!

Comment: @Sindu_ thanks! I have updated it!  Could you please think about mark it,  then others can know the error solved and reference from you? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this thread got the answer it needed, but for future searches... the Azure SQL Data Sync within Azure SQL Database **does** support syncing temporal tables.

You just have to remember to not sync the system generated date columns (because you can't explicitly INSERT into those columns, and Data Sync will try :-))

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data#sync-req-lim

HTH

Comment: SQL DATA SYNC tool is only used when the schemas in source and target table match, right? How would you sync 2 tables when the schema is different?

Comment: @OliverNilsen you can specify which columns you want to sync, so the schemas don't need to match exactly (the target table could only have a subset of the columns)